# Trouble using SharedPreferences to persist data

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save the value of swipesRemaining via the SharedPreferences interface. The value of the variable does not persist. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. 
Here is the source code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView swipes;
    private int swipesRemaining = 11;
    private static final String SWIPES = "swipes";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        swipes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        loadInt();

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            swipesRemaining = savedInstanceState.getInt(SWIPES);
        }

        updateText(swipesRemaining);
    }

    public void save(View view) {
        saveInt("key", swipesRemaining);
    }

    public void reset(View view) {
        swipesRemaining = 11;
        updateText(swipesRemaining);
    }

    public void swipe(View view) {
        if(swipesRemaining > 1) {
            swipesRemaining--;
            updateText(swipesRemaining);
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "You ran out of swipes!...Resetting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            reset(view);
        }
    }

    private void updateText(int swipesRemaining) {
        swipes.setText("Swipes: " + swipesRemaining);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putInt(SWIPES, swipesRemaining );
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void saveInt(String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void loadInt() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        swipesRemaining = sharedPreferences.getInt("key", swipesRemaining);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Swipes left: " + swipesRemaining, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling your save method?

Comment: The save method is called from an onClick event

Comment: I got ur typo, Its on the loadInt() method, you should use it as loadInt(String key), by pass ing the same key that you have passed in saveInt(String key, ...). and also change the "key" into key inside loadInt() function